# ITfoxtec SAML 2.0: Dynamic configuration

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I would like to know if it's possible to configure the library during runtime (Saml2Configuration). We want to have the ability to set the configuration options and get them from DB.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes no problem. You can populate the Saml2Configuration at runtime on load or in the controller just before setting the Saml2Configuration object in the constructor.

Here an example from FoxIDs https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs/blob/master/src/FoxIDs/Logic/Saml/SamlAuthnDownLogic.cs#L70